# drupal 6 php array of arrays not working

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, drupal-6

I'm trying to put values into name arrays from a table and array entries are over-riding each other

Code:

```
$list = array();
$name = db_query("SELECT name FROM {name_list}");
while ($num = db_fetch_array($name)){
$list[$num['name']]=array('title'=>$num['name']);
}
$values = db_query("SELECT id,name1,name2 FROM {status}");
while ($val = db_fetch_array($values)){
$list[$val['name1']] = array($val['id'] =>$val['id']);
$list[$val['name2']] = array($val['id'] =>$val['id']);
}
$output .= dprint_r($list);
```

The first while loop writes the titles of each array which are the names from the name db table. 
The table:

```
name
Alice
Kate
Jason
John
Sam
```

the second while loop goes into the status table which looks something like:

```
id name1 name2
1   Alice Kate
2   Jason Kate
3   Kate  Alice
4   Jason John
```

The final arrays should look something like:
Alice array (
1,3);
Jason array (
2,4);
Kate array (
1,2,3);
Sam array (
);
 etc...

Instead its looking like
  alice (3) Jason(4) Kate(3) etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have no drupal for testing the error seems clear. Use the `[]` operator to push elements to the end of the id-per-name array. Try :

```
$list = array();
$name = db_query("SELECT name FROM {name_list}");
while ($num = db_fetch_array($name)){
    $list[$num['name']]=array(); // initialize as empty array. you won't need the name
                                 // twice as its already the index to $list
}
$values = db_query("SELECT id,name1,name2 FROM {status}");

while ($val = db_fetch_array($values)){
    $list[$val['name1']][] = $val['id']; // add id to the first name's list
    $list[$val['name2']][] = $val['id']; // add id to the second name's list
}
```

Comment: I'll try this now. why the second [] part?

Comment: this worked, i get a blank array also [] => Array ( ). do you know why that could be ?

Comment: @ingrid I've updated a little bit. Does it work? I have no drupal for testing

Comment: it does work; i didn't know [] did stuff (still a little confused how it works). Secondly, if some names have no entries, why wouldn't I see an empty array like [Sam] => Array( )

Comment: You should see. Didn't you? ... For [] see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: Oh thank you!  I think this might be an issue of how dprint_r() works in drupal. There isn't a good reason for the arrays to not exist. Thanks again :), Also thanks for the link.

Comment: You are welcome.. Search for 'Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax' on the following link.. this is the correct explanation of [] ... good luck! :) http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php